# Tap down and tap up events?

Tags: android, events, click, touch

Are there events for tapping down/up (two different ones) on an element in Android? Click seems essentially the same as tapping "up" (removing your finger from the screen) but there isn't really a good tap down event as far as I can tell.

I've been messing with the Touch event, but it triggers for any contact between finger and object, including gestures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                   //my action
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Doing the ACTION_UP is just the same